# Invoke operator via reflection on built-in types .net 2.0

Tags: c#, reflection, operators, clr

All,

Is it possible to invoke operators (such as +, ++) via reflection on built-in types in .net 2.0?
It appears, you can't! When I tried to access op_Increment on int32, the operator was not defined. I read that operators on built-in types are handled by the compiler and are not defined on the actual type ... please confirm.

Otherwise, is there another way? I know later version of C# has dynamic keyword, what are my options?

Comment: I have a hack solution and that is to check the type, cast it, and do my operation but that's very verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. On the built in types (bool, byte, short, int, long, float, double) operations like `+` and `++` are mapped to IL instructions and don't have a corresponding `op_Increment` method, for example.

`decimal` does allow you to, even though it looks like a built-in type. `string` is an interesting one as calls to `+` are mapped to `String.Concat` and its variants.

Take a look at this [generic operators](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html) article, it may help (it's by Jon Skeet and Marc Gravell)

Comment: Thanks Sean,- I don't know if I want to include 3.5 assembly in my 2.0 project just for that one hack I have in my code.

Comment: Expression class does not support Incr, Decr in 3.5 which is what I need.